# Cloudwatch Alarm across all dimensions based on metric name for custom metrics

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, cloudwatch-alarms

We are publishing custom Cloudwatch metrics from our service and want to set up alarms if the value for a metric name breaches a threshold for any dimension. Here are the metrics we are publishing:

1. Namespace=SameName, MetricName=Fault, Dimensions=[**Operation=A**, Program=ServiceName]
2. Namespace=SameName, MetricName=Fault, Dimensions=[**Operation=B**, Program=ServiceName]
3. Namespace=SameName, MetricName=Fault, Dimensions=[**Operation=C**, Program=ServiceName]

We want to set up an alarm so that a `Fault` across any dimension puts it into the `Alarm` state.

As you can see, the value for dimension Operation is different. Currently, we only have these 3 operations, so I understand we can use metric math to set up this alarm. But I am sure we will get to a point where this will keep growing.

I am able to use SEARCH expression + aggregate across search expression to generate a graph for it, but it does not let me create an alarm saying `The expression for an alarm must include at least one metric.`

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alarming directly on SEARCH is not supported yet. You would have to create a metric math expression where you list all 3 metrics, then create an expression that takes the max of the 3, like `MAX(METRICS())`. Make sure only the expression is marked as visible so that there is only 1 line on the graph.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Dejan, alarming on search isn't supported yet on Cloudwatch.
Another limitation is that you can only add [up to 10 metrics to a metric math expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html), which you can overcome with the [new composite alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create_Composite_Alarm.html).

If you would consider using a 3rd party service, you can try [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com).

With DataDog you can import your cloudwatch metrics and set up [multi-alarms](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/monitor_types/metric/?tab=threshold#alert-grouping) which follow (and automatically discover) all tags under a specific metric.

There might be other services that offer this kind of feature, but I specifically have experience with this tool.